# What is the max length of Title field for an Apple Watch notification?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, apple-watch

I've consulted [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW1), but I don't see anything about the maximum length of Apple Watch notification title.

Note - if this question is better-suited for Ask Different, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

here are good posts about it : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/TextandLabels.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html

*I think text goes down each line when it reaches its maximum length in one line, so if you are developing an app, you could write long text and count how many charachters are there :)*